# WindowsAzure.Storage nuget package install problems

Tags: dll, dependencies, nuget, azure-storage, nuget-package

When I attempt to install WindowsAzure.Storage via nuget (using the command found here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/)

> Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 8.4.0

I get the following error.

> Install-Package : Unable to find package PlTagHelpers. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program 
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 8.4.0
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCom 
>      mand

Install-Package : Unable to find package PlStorage. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program 
Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 8.4.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCom 
   mand

Install-Package : Unable to find package PlBlobLibrary. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program 
Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 8.4.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCom 
   mand

Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Heartland'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 8.4.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCom 
   mand

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you please provide your exact install command in your post?

Comment: Yes, I just did.

Here it is: Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 8.4.0

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to find package PlTagHelpers. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline

According to your exception, I assume that when you try to install `WindowsAzure.Storage` that you choose the  package source `Microsoft Visual Studio Offline`, please have a try to select package source **nuget.org** or **All** then it should work.

[image]

[image]

We also need to note the SDK dependencies, more details please refer to [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/)